# Force re-render after app state change react-native

Tags: react-native

I'd like to know if there is a way to re-render the app after the app state change.
For example how can I re-render the RN layout of a page when the app state changes from background to active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a render should only depend on your state and props, so you can check if there is new data to put there (for instance, if your data comes from a network request) and call `setState` or pass the new props. You can also force a render manually if you want using [`forceUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate), but the layout should remain the same, as the data that it depends on should be equal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry but I have another question on this argument. Is there a way to set a state and re-render for example a `View` inside the `render()` when the app state changes?

Comment: Sure, every time you call `setUpdate` a new render will be issued, so you can just use that to trigger the rendering.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know where can I find some examples on how to use it? I read the RN doc, but it doesn't provide any kind of examples about this.

Comment: The whole lifecycle methods from RN are taken from React, so any React tutorial will do. You can check the project page for an introduction to that: https://facebook.github.io/react/

Answer (score 0):

You can call setState from your AppState listener https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate